# ¿Query con Where multiple?

Tags: sql, postgresql

estoy buscando hacer una consulta donde mi `WHERE` tenga múltiples `string` de la misma variable por ejemplo:

```
"SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE variable = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
```

y que el mismo me aplicara la condición, no se si me explico.

un ejemplo escrito seria:

> Buscar un buque cuando este presente la coordenada X,X,X,X,X,X,X,X,X,X (una sola variable de coordenadas).

Comment: puedes hacerlo con `ìn` como indica la [documentación](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con el operador `IN` que permite el uso de múltiples valores, de este modo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE variable IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

Lo anterior regresará una lista de valores donde variable coincida con uno o varios de los parámetros pasados dentro de la función `IN`

O bien podrías con operadores lógicos como el `OR` hacerlo así:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE  variable = 1 
                        OR variable = 2  
                        OR variable = 3
                        OR variable = 4;
```

Comment: Me a funcionado, muchas gracias.